# OpenCV: Couldn't read video stream from file

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv

I'm trying to output a video from file using OpenCV 3.4.0. Xcode gives an error message: OpenCV: Couldn't read video stream from file. When i capture video from cam xcode run successfull. I try install ffmpeg 3.4.1 and don't know what headers i need to include. It's all on OSX 10.12 Sierra

Comment: Please provide more information. What code are you using? How was OpenCV built (with ffmpeg included?)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found solution, i point wrong path to file `"~/Desktop/test.mp4"` just changed to `"/Users/jameson/Desktop/test.mp4"` apparantly opencv not enough abridged version of path