# opencv cannot read the mp4 (python)

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

[environment]
language: python
mac-os: ventura 13.0.1

the code is following:

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('lane.mp4')
```

when I use cv2.VideoCapture(path), it shows

```
OpenCV: Couldn't read video stream from file "lane.mp4"
```

I've search for solutions on this website but failed to find what's wrong with the code
put the entire path is still failed, the video is in the file

can anybody help me? thanks a lot

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48761809/2570277) answer help?

Comment: `assert os.path.exists("lane.mp4"), os.getcwd()`